# SQL selecting multiple MAX and MIN - Python

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I have a program which stores scores for students within a database. I want to select the max score for each student. At the moment, only one student with the highest score out of all students is returned, and not the highest score for each student. Can anyone help me out with this ? (FYI there is one "score" column which has a list of scores stored in it)

```
def ClassSort():
myFile = sqlite3.connect("scores.db")
c = myFile.cursor()

clear()
classNo = input("Enter the class number you would like to sort... ")
clear()
type = input("How would you like to sort ? \n 1 - Highest score, with students in alphabetical order \n 2 - Highest score, highest to lowest \n 3 - Average score, highest to lowest \n... ")

if type == "1":
    c.execute('SELECT MIN(score), name FROM scores WHERE classNo = (?)', (classNo,))                
if type == "2":
    c.execute('SELECT MAX(score), name FROM scores WHERE classNo = (?)', (classNo,))
if type == "3":
    c.execute('SELECT AVG(score), name FROM scores WHERE classNo = (?)', (classNo,))        

row = c.fetchall()
row = ', '.join(map(str, row))
print(row)

myFile.commit()
myFile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `GROUP BY` statement. Aggregation functions in sql are usually most useful with a `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT MAX(score), name FROM scores WHERE classNo = (?) GROUP BY name
```